# row reading and editing in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am new to Fortran, I am trying to write a program to read a .txt file in which i have 24480 rows and ~ 6000 columns.
In each row (as individuals) i have genotypes indicated as 1 and 2, which if, for example, in row one, i have had 204 genotypes, first half of this genotypes (=102) belongs to individual's sire and second half of genotypes belongs to individual's dam. In addition each row has not equal values. So, how can i define for Fortran to read this file row by row and divide each row to two and put beside each element (i) to the mean+i.

For example i show two rows of my file as brief:
row1: 112122121112122111112121111211122121111121
row2: 21112111112112222121112121211121221212121111121112 1212

And so on.
Any help would be appreciated in advance.

Comment: Try with the right tag. You'll have greater chance for answer.

Comment: Sorry can you specify clearly what is your desired result. Best show an example result.

Comment: First i want to read and enter my data from text file into fortran and choosing genotypes of interest, second, choosing individuals of interest and finally producing a genotype file for selected genotypes and individuals for example as a 2 dimensional matrix.

Comment: Please give us an example of desired output. I happen to know what genotype or ATCG bases are, but it doesn't help me at all to understand, what you want from your description of your data.

Comment: ok, yes you are right. i have to describe more. So, i have a very big dataset of markers(genes or genotypes) which characterized as 1 and 2. in the data set i just have 1 and 2 (not ATCG). ok, in this data set, i have m row including m individual and n column which representing markers.In addition each row has different number of markers (as 1,2). Ok, i need to read each row by fortran and define that each row is a chromosome of each individual which inherited by mom(dam) and dad(sire). and then divide each row into two and  say that first half of row belongs dad and the other half belongs mom

Comment: and after introducing this data set to Fortran, I want to be able to choose and print interesting markers in each row and interesting individuals at the whole of data set in a new file.

Comment: So suppose below lines as my two first lines in data set: row1: 12111221112121 which including 14 markers which first seven (1211122) markers belong to his dad and second seven markers belong to his mom. row 2: 1112221212121112212122112111121212212211122221 which including 46 markers, respectively. thank you for your patience

Comment: i would like to share you a part of my data set as an instance. So please see this link: http://www.4shared.com/photo/O4fWnt4w/marker_sample.html

Comment: Please ignore those blue part of data set. those columns are ID of individual, Live status(1 alive and 0 dead), Chromosome number respectively.

Answer (score 2):

you need to read each line as a string, get its length with len_trim(), then read each half into integer arrays:

```
     character*10000 line

     read(unit,'(a)')line
     len=len_trim(line)
     read(line,'(10000i1)')a(:len/2),b(:len/2)
```